# CORS request won't work in Firefox, works in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, python, firefox, bottle

This fiddle works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/u5pugnbn/

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Get Data" onclick="getData()"/>
    <h1 id="output"></h1>
  </body>

  <script src ="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var API_URL = "http://andr3w321.pythonanywhere.com";

function getData() {
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = API_URL + "/hello";
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        output.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      } else {
        output.innerHTML = "Error: " + xhr.statusText;
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    output.innerHTML = "Error: " + xhr.statusText;
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

Python bottle server file

```
from bottle import default_app, route, run, template, static_file, url, get, redirect, response, request

# allow requests from other domains
def enable_cors(fn):
    def _enable_cors(*args, **kwargs):
        # set CORS headers
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token'

        if request.method != 'OPTIONS':
            # actual request; reply with the actual response
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return _enable_cors


@route('/hello', method=['OPTIONS', 'GET'])
@enable_cors
def hello():
    return "hello"

application = default_app()
```

Uploading the static index.html to a domain and changing the `Allow-Origin` from `*` to the specific domain did not seem to help.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. What is the intended result?

Comment: The h1 header should populate with "hello" if the request succeeds.  Hmmm I'm running the latest firefox 40.0.3 and just updated from 39.  Not sure if that has any affect.  As I said it works in Chromium for me just fine, but not firefox.  It given an error in the console as freezing on ` xhr.open("GET", url, true);` line.

Comment: works in 40.0.3 (windows) and 42.0 for that matter

Comment: Okay thanks for testing.  I'm on ubuntu.

Comment: check your firefox developer tools browser console andn network tab for any clues as to what is happening

Comment: Posted the problem.  Thanks for helping track it down!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out Privacy badger was blocking the request.  After I disabled it after visiting index.html it works fine.